# Core data bad access on relationship - fixed by changing the relationship name?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I spent yesterday afternoon with a very strange issue. I have a core data model. in simple terms there is a call entity and a new WOs entity with an optional  one to many relationship between call and new WO.

Call->>newWO

the relationship was called newWosForCall on the call object and callForNewWO on the newWO object.

I started getting bad access errors. To help debug, i created a new view controller with a single button and simplified code. I blanked the emulator so there is nothing in core data. I added a single call object to call data. There where no newWO objects in core data.

On the button click I accessed the data for the relationship ie

```
Call *aCall=.... get a call object from a fetch request
if (aCall.newWOsForCall.count==0)
{NSLog(@"no new wos");}
else
{NSLog(@"there are WOs");
```

and on first click everything is fine. click the button again and I get a bad access error. this behaviour was consistent - first access was OK, then second access in any way to the calls .newWOsForCall relationship caused an error.

The short version of the afternoon was: I tried deleting the relationship on both sides and recreated it. I cleaned the project and then recompiled and had the same behaviour. after much swearing and checking that other relationships off the call object worked OK in desperation I simply renamed the replationship from newWOsForCall to pleaseDamnWellWork (real name had more swearing). I recompiled, changed the code on the button to have the new relationship name.... and it works for every click. non bad access errors at all.

just to prove this was the issue, I renamed the relationship back to newWOsForCall and started to get the same behaviour as before - the first click was fine, the second gave a bad access error.

I know that I have working code - and i'm very grateful for that, but has anyone come across something similar? any idea why it didn't like that specific name for the relationship?

I have used similar naming conventions for other relationships and they are fine - eg call->>LogFile relationship is called logFilesForCall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain method names have special meaning and handling in ARC. This is partly for historical reasons, and is required to make everything work. For example:

> Methods in the alloc, copy, init, mutableCopy, and new families are implicitly marked **attribute**((ns_returns_retained)). This may be suppressed by explicitly marking the method **attribute**((ns_returns_not_retained)).

So, by using the word `new` at the start of the method (which returns the relationship) you're telling ARC something that isn't true.

Also, in the context of a persistent data store, what does 'new' in 'newWO' mean? Is it going to make sense later on when you fetch an object from the store?

So, you need to change the name, and you should generally change the name of the entity too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I understand that the word "new" could be a keyword, but "newWOsForCall" is not a keyword, so would not ahve expected that to cause an issue. Something to be aware of i guess. so you wwould expect a realtionship called allocatedTickets to also cause issues because it starts with "alloc"?

I really would have expected it to be able to differentiate the cases here. It's definelty something to remember though.


the term newWO is short for new Works Order. it doesn't mean new as in create a new instance. Not a great name I agree, but is a roll over from their legacy system

Comment: 'new' isn't a language keyword, but it is a word with special meaning.  In particular, 'new' followed by a class name is a common constructor method naming scheme (which your method name matches). 'alloc' doesn't have quite the same associations, and capitalisation is also important, but you should stay away from that naming too.

Comment: the joys of different languages eh! Thanks!